# Tokens in TextFields SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I´m currently developing an Eclipse4 RCP Application and I was wondering if there is a possibility to define tokens in SWT Text Fields, so that they are not accessible characterwise.

So for example I have a Text Field and I want to make tokens that match "**[anytext]**" not accessible characterwise. (Where the parenthesis define the token)

That means: I cannot put my cursor inside the parenthesis and if I press delete directly in front of the left parenthesis or backspace directly behind the right parenthesis, the whole token gets deleted.

I´m currently doing it with listeners but that seems somehow a little to complex and expensive, as I need a KeyListener with lots of logic and a mouse listener to prevent clicks inside the token and an adjusted Drop Listener as Drops inside token shouldn´t be allowed neither obviously.

Am I just missing some fancy way of doing it?

Hope you can help me, 
thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify: are you making something similar to StackOwerflow tags functionality?

Comment: no, but in a way that´s what I need.
To give you the big picture: I have a text, (call it a variable) and those variables can appear as tokens in other textfields (in these parenthesis: [variable]). As the text of the variable gets changed, all tokens change their text accordingly. The tokens shouldn´t get manipulated, but one should be able to delete them (the whole token).

Comment: There is no fancy way, lots of listeners is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText` that provides rich features than `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text`.  JavaEditor does the same functionality that you are looking like refactor change variable name, change gets reflected whereever this variable is used.